# YouCompleteMe for VIM

Tags: git, vim, autocomplete, youcompleteme

I have downloaded YCM frim https://github.com/Valloric/YouCompleteMe source, and ./install.py command gives this error. 
 * I have activated repository using git init
 * I downloaded ycmd seperately and tested
still ERROR doesn't stop.

```
ERROR: some folders in /home/user/.vim/bundle/YouCompleteMe/third_party/ycmd/third_party are empty; you probably forgot to run:
    git submodule update --init --recursive
```

Comment: Why don't you try installing it with plugin manager like https://github.com/junegunn/vim-plug ?

Comment: Have you run `git submodule update --init --recursive`?

Comment: Actually it was long ago, but I remember that, I have been using plugin-manager. It did not solve my problem